# Publishing media from Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, streaming, media, azure-media-services

Is it possible to publish media  in Azure Media Services for indeterminate period of time in such way, that client will simply download the media file? My research currently shown:

- I can create a OnDemandOrigin Locator, but it is prepared for streaming media, not simply downloading them.
- I can create a Shared Access Signature locator, but it always requires a AccessPolicy object, which restricts the period of the locator's work time to a predefined value.

Answer (score 2):

You can create Sas locator and specify datetime which is far ahead. Expiration time is required attribute when you creating locator

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you could consider looking at the file located in blob storage, and offer access to that container. This way the user can download the finished file at any point.

This post has more information about [restricting access to containers.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-manage-access-to-resources/)

**Overview**

By default, only the owner of the storage account may access storage resources within that account. If your service or application needs to make these resources available to other clients without sharing your access key, you have the following options for permitting access:

- You can set a container's permissions to permit anonymous read access to the container and its blobs. Anonymous read access is available only for containers and blobs.
- You can expose a resource via a shared access signature, which enables you to delegate restricted access to a container, blob, table, queue, file share, or file by specifying the interval for which the resources are available and the permissions that a client will have to it.
- You can use a stored access policy to manage shared access signatures for a container or its blobs, for a queue, for a table, or for a file share or its files. The stored access policy gives you an additional measure of control over your shared access signatures and also provides a straightforward means to revoke them.